# How to listen http request from browser in proxy server

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

I am creating my own proxy server. Howerver, i don't know how to listen to browser. Moreover, i have some questions:

1. Do i need to listen to request from browser?
2. Do i have to display the received content on browser or just print all the html tags in console screen?

I think as every proxy server works, my program would get request from the client (browser), forward it to Web Server then receive the content from server, finally forward to the client.

```
   #pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <process.h> /* for getpid() and the exec..() family */
#include <direct.h> 
using namespace std;
bool checkSubString(char *str, char*substr)
{
    if (strstr(str, substr) != NULL)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
int main()
{
    WSADATA wsData;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsOK = WSAStartup(ver, &wsData);

    if (wsOK != 0)
    {
        cerr << "cant init winsock" << endl; return 0;
    }

    char message[1024];
    int sockcheck = 0;
    sockaddr_in server_input_addr;

    memset(&server_input_addr, '0', sizeof(server_input_addr));
    memset(&message, '0', sizeof(message));
    sockcheck = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockcheck < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Error while creating socket!!!\n";
        return 0;
    }

    server_input_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_input_addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_input_addr.sin_port = htons(8888);
    bind(sockcheck, (sockaddr*)&server_input_addr, sizeof(server_input_addr));
    listen(sockcheck, 5);
    int connFd = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int client_length = sizeof(server_input_addr);
    while (1) {

        connFd = accept(sockcheck, (sockaddr*)&server_input_addr, &client_length);
        if (connFd < 0)
        {
            cerr << "\nError in accepting message from browser"; return 0;
        }
        n = _read(connFd, message, 1023);
        if (n > 0)
        {
            cerr << "ERROR reading from socket\n";
        }
        _write(connFd, "Message received", 15);
        _close(connFd);
    }
    cout << "\nSuccess!!!\n";
}
```

Comment: "*my program would get request from the client (browser), forward it to Web Server then receive the content from server, finally forward to the client.*" - that is exactly how a proxy works. It should not care about the actual content at all, only care about forwarding arbitrary data back and forth. And in fact, when proxying HTTPS, that is all it can do, as it can't look at the content at all since it is encrypted. I suggest you read up on how various proxy protocols actually work, like SOCKS, the HTTP `CONNECT` method, etc

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I have read many articles about some proxy protocols, HTTP connect method. However, i still do not get what i need. Could you please give me more keywords so i can Google it? My proxy server has port at 8888. Still, i need to receive message from browser like chrome to handle.

Comment: the code you have shown does *nothing* to implement any of those protocols I mentioned. Have you even tried anything once you read about them? If you want to implement a SOCKS proxy then you need to read requests according to the SOCKS protocol. If you want to implement an HTTP proxy, you need to read requests according to the HTTP protocol. And so on. These are well-documented protocols. What have you done so far to implement these protocols beyond the code you have shown so far?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau. Yes, I did read about HTTP request. My program would support GET and POST method. However, my problem is i do not know how to receive message from browser so that i can not do anything. Just that.

Comment: you already know how to *listen* for requests, now you need to *read and parse* them, and *respond* to them. [SOCKS](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1928) is fairly trivial to implement from scratch, but [HTTP](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616) is not. If you don't understand the basics of things like reading/writing variable-length delimited strings, binary data (byte arrays, integers, etc), and such then you are not ready to tackle this proxy project yet. StackOverflow is not a tutorial site. Get yourself some good books on network programming.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for your advice. I have updated my code but it still does not work. I think my problem does not occurs in the code, it is in how i configure my browser.

Comment: yes, you need to configure your browser (or any other app) to connect to your proxy, that is not done automatically (unless you implement support for things like [Automatic Proxy Detection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/automatic-proxy-detection)). With the new code you have added, you still have a LONG way to go before you will have a working proxy